# Firebase MLKit QRCode scanning fails without error stack trace

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I tried to add a QR code scanner to my Android app with the following method:

```
fun scanQRCode(bitmap: Bitmap): String? {
    val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
            .build()
    val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);
    val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    var id: String? = ""
    detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            id = null
            return@addOnSuccessListener
        }
        for (firebaseBarcode in it) {
            val a = it[0].rawValue ?: ""
            id = a

        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        id = null
    }
    return id
}
```

When running the app neither the `onFailure` nor the `onSuccess` callbacks are triggered. My id returns always null and I get the following warnings in logcat:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode:0
D/BarcodeNativeHandle: Cannot load feature, fall back to load dynamite module.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode:1
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode, version >= 1
```

I already checked for my internet connection on my testing phone (HTC Desire 19+) and deleted the local cache of Google Play Services.

My gradle dependencies for the qr scanning are the following:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'
```

Anyone ran into this before? Is it rather an issue in my codebase or a firebase issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was actually in my codebase. The return value for `scanQRCode()` was the scanned result value, but the scanning process is asynchronus, so it always returned an empty string. 
I fixed the error by adding a callback to pass the value:

```
fun scanQRCode(bitmap: Bitmap, callback: QRInterface) {
    val options = FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
            .build()
    val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options);
    val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            callback.onQRScanFinished(null)
            return@addOnSuccessListener
        }
        for (firebaseBarcode in it) {
            val a = it[0].rawValue ?: ""
            callback.onQRScanFinished(a)
            Log.d("QRScanner", "successful")

        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        it.printStackTrace()
        callback.onQRScanFinished(null)

        Log.d("QRScanner", "failed")
    }
}
```